# Why does {{ }} not show a field that's assigned to a variable if there's an array assigned to it?

Tags: angularjs

In my company code I see:

```
test.active = [];
test.active.$selectedRow = null;
```

Is this a valid thing to do. I know it works okay but it seems that if a variable is an array then it's odd that it has a field.

When I view this with AngularJS using {{ test.active }} it does not seem to show the $selectedRow. It just shows the array contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things are in play here. First of which is `$interpolate`, which is responsible for interpolating a string such as `Hello {{ world }}` with `$scope.world = "world"` to `Hello world`.

`$interpolate` doesn't do a lot of magic with the type of `world`: if it's a string, it returns the string, if it's a number, it stringifies the number. If it's anything else, it goes to `angular.toJson`. You can find this in [the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/aa268560064e5875bd471da3f7d1ebc2f9e6b3b7/src/ng/interpolate.js#L266).

JSON, in its turn, serialises the array as @Mosho describes: it iterates from 0 to `length`, as shown in this [implementation](https://github.com/bestiejs/json3/blob/dec5c2a5dc723ff867caa32a81ed93ab814f7426/lib/json3.js#L484) and the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.3):

> The representation of arrays includes only the elements between zero
>   and array.length – 1 inclusive. Named properties are excluded from the
>   stringification.

You should, of course, be able to do `{{ test.active.$selectedRow }}`, and you should also be able to inspect the value in a JavaScript console.

Answer (score 0):

it's valid. Such properties won't be iterated on using array prototype methods (but will when using `for ... in`, but they are objects after all, so nothing wrong with it.

Not appearing when you use angular's templating is probably due to it recognizing the object as an array and iterating over the properties with indexes from 0 to `length` only.

Answer (score 0):

This is valid syntax.  If you do this:

```
console.log(test.active);
```

you will see the $selectedRow = null, but it will not appear when iterating since it is not a property